# String or Integer conversion to ASCII

Tags: c++

I need help converting an unsigned int or string into a char or ASCII integer. I can't access my switch case statement because the token value is being interpreted incorrectly. My starting data type is a string, taken from a queue.

The token is type integer but not considered ASCII. I looked at conversions from string to ASCII or string to Char but im confused on how to implement it: all the definitions hard coded a string Char[] = "string"; while i need to pass a string by reference.

```
while (queueObj.IsEmpty() == false)                         // While the queue has nodes
        {           
            string queueString = queueObj.head->dataQueue;  // Get data from Queue node
            int token = std::stoul(queueString);            // Converts string data to integer value
            
            switch (token)                                  // compares the value of the queue data for stack operation
            {
                case '+':
                {
                  // switch case operations
                }
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of what strings might be assigned to `queueString`, and what value you would like to end up with in `token` for each of them?  That would help clarify what sort of behavior your are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Btw if all you need is a `const char *` pointing to the contents of your `std::string` as a char-array, then `queueString.c_str()` will return that for you.

Comment: A string example would be:  "3 5 * 6 -", This string is then converted into a single character strings:  '3' '5' '*' '6' '-'   these individual strings are stored in queue, then dequed and sent through a switch case statement

Comment: Do you expect `std::stoul("+")` to result in `'+'`? `std::stoul` converts a sequence of digits to the corresponding integer and throws an exception if it fails. You need to check (or keep track of) what kind of token you have.

Comment: The program is checking a random postfix string (example: "8 4 - ") and storing each string value into a linked list queue (first node = "8", second node = '4', third node = '-'). The queueObj accesses the queue class, goes to the head pointer (which is the head of the queue) and takes the first value of the string (which is 8 in the example) Then it stores it into a string queueString and converts the string into a token value of type int. That integer value is compared in the switch case statements. In other words it should check for an ASCII type integer to see if (+, -, *, etc) is there

Answer (score 0):

I suggest explicitly checking for a supported operator by mapping the string representations to an `enum`:

```
enum Operation { kPlus, kMinus, /* and so on */ };

const std::map<std::string, Operation> operations {
  {"+", kPlus},
  {"-", kMinus},
};
```

You can now attempt look up each token as follows:

```
string queueString = queueObj.head->dataQueue;
if (auto it = operations.find(queueString); it != cend(operations)) {
  // It's a known operation
  switch (*it) {
    case kPlus: ...; break
    case kMinus: ...; break
  }
} else {
  // It's a number
  auto number = std::stoul(queueString);
}
```